# Load some variables from PHP Script using JavaScript and/or C# (Unity3D)

Tags: javascript, c#, php, unity-game-engine

I have difficult project in Unity Game Engine, i need to create script that load variables from PHP file on server. My PHP script is:

```
<?php
 $MasterServer = "SomeIP1";
 $MasterServer2 = "SomeIP2";
 $MasterServer3 = "SomeIP3";

 echo "1 Server = ".$MasterServer;
 echo "2 Server = ".$MasterServer2;
 echo "3 Server = ".$MasterServer3;
?>
```

And the result of this:

> ```
>  1 Server = SomeIP1
>  2 Server = SomeIP2
>  3 Server = SomeIP3
> ```

How to read these (as variables) in C# and/or JS (Unity3D)?

Comment: `responseFromServer.Split('\n').Select(v => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(v.Split('=')[0], v.Spit('=')[1]));` will result with `{ "1 Server ", " SomeIP1" }, { "2 Server ", " SomeIP2" }...`

Answer (score 3):

Don't do that. That is the appropriate answer to your question.  Use xml or json to hold the data.

On the php side, construct all those data into one json string. On the C# side, receive it with the [`WWW`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) class then [deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239705/serialize-and-deserialize-json-and-json-array-in-unity/36244111#36244111) the json into object. You can then access 1 Server, 2 Server and 3 Server data from it.

**PHP**:

Send to Unity:

```
{"server1":"SomeIP1","server2":"SomeIP2","server3":"SomeIP3"}
```

You have to replace the SomeIP1,SomeIP2 and SomeIP3 with the IPs.

**C#**:

```
[Serializable]
public class ServerInfo
{
    public string server1;
    public string server2;
    public string server3;
}
```

....

```
IEnumerator downLoadFromServer()
{
    WWW www = new WWW("yourUrl");
    yield return www;
    string json = www.text;

    ServerInfo serverInfo = JsonUtility.FromJson<ServerInfo>(json);
    Debug.Log("server1: " + serverInfo.server1);
    Debug.Log("server2: " + serverInfo.server2);
    Debug.Log("server3: " + serverInfo.server3);
}
```

I suggest you spend time and learn how json works.